# Asmx webservice Xmlhttprequest content-type

Tags: javascript, web-services, xmlhttprequest, asmx

I have a piece of javascript code for accessing a asmx webservice

```
var xml = 'xml=&lt;Webservice&gt;&lt;Parameters&gt;&lt;Parameter name=&quot;PARTCODE&quot; value=&quot;WSA10029&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Parameters&gt;&lt;/Webservice&gt;';
        try {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url, false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(xml);
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Error occured in XMLHttpRequest: ' + xhr.statusText + '  ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status);
        }
```

The webservice receives the request but the parameter xml is empty at the webservice side. i've tried many different Content-Types but none of them work.

Data data I want to send is xml, therefor I htmlencoded the xml.

Comment: Did you check what is passed in request in network. Check in network what is there in request.

Comment: In the request is a form data htmlencoded xml string. Checked it with FireFox Dev tools.

Comment: If at server side xml is consumed, you need to use application/xml as content-type

Comment: Still invalid content type. Server side webservice accepts a string as xml.

Comment: Can you add code of your webservice

Comment: <WebMethod()>
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
    Public Function Calculate_v2(xml As String) As XmlDocument
        xml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xml)
        Dim XmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        Dim ReturnXmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        Dim CalcPrice As Decimal = 0
        Dim CalcWeight As Decimal = 0
        Dim Sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim Response As New XmlDocument
        Dim ProductTypeId As JIBA.Libs.Enums.TypeOfCalc_v2

Comment: Then you should pass text/xml as content type

Comment: Still invalid content type with text/xml

Comment: I can say try with application/* or text/plain

Comment: Tried both. Still same error about invalid content type. Application/www-form urlencode triggers the Webservices but the parameter is an empty string

Comment: Figured it out, needed to replace the & sign by %26.